# Interrupt problem: timer, x86,boot sector,real mode, 8295A PIC, 8253, assembly

Tags: assembly, timer, x86, interrupt, real-mode

If disable hardware interrupts (comment off line 37), the code in lines 38~40 will keep calling procedure task0 and task1 in turn which print letter C and S separately(print the full screen and start from the upper left corner to print again).
Problem is once enable interrupts (line 37), and comment off lines 38~40, program does not alternatively switch from task0 to task1. It only prints a letter S and probably with flashing time by time.

Code is in the boot sector (the first 512 bytes). Problem should be in one of the following:
Lines 20-21 set the handler to IVT table at the 8th handler location;
Lines 23-30 set timer 8293;
Lines 77-92 is the timer interrupt handler.

To run the program, copy the following source code into a file, name it ep3.s, and key in the following line in Terminal (QEMU emulator, as, and ld required on Linux to run):

```
as -o ep3.o ep3.s;ld ep3.o -o ep3 -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary;sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=ep3 -cpu max
```

Source code:

```
.code16                 #! tell the assembler to generate 16-bit code
.globl _start           # comments start with '!',to be altered at a later stage
.section .text
_start:                  
    cli                 # Turn off interrupts
    xor %ax, %ax        # Initialize the segments, set the stack to grow down from
    mov %ax, %ds        # start of bootloader at _start. SS:SP=0x0000:0x7c00
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $_start, %sp
    mov %ax, %es
    sti                 # Enable interrupts
    cld                 # Set direction flag forward for string instructions
    ljmp *jump_offset

main: # main program starts
    #call setup_ivt
    cli
    movl $system_interrupt, %eax # set IVT int 0x80
    movl %eax, 0x0200(,1) 
    movl $timer_interrupt, %eax  # set timer handler
    movl %eax, 0x0020(,1)        # timer part 1

    movb $0x36, %al     #  8293 timer setting
    movl $0x43, %edx
    outb %al, %dx
    movl $11930, %eax   # about every 1/100 second
    movl $0x40, %edx
    outb %al, %dx
    movb %ah, %al
    outb %al, %dx

    mov  $0xE, %al      #  8259A, mask other interrupts except interrput IRQ1
    out  %al, $0x21
    mov  $0xF, %al
    out  %al, $0xA1

    sti
#l1: call task0
#    call task1
#    jmp l1

    jmp .

write_char:             # set %ax, SCN_SEL,scn_pos before call               
    pushl %ebx          # put %ebx to stack
    pushw %es
    movw  SCN_SEL, %es  
    movl  scn_pos, %ebx
    cmpl  $2000, %ebx
    jb    1f
    call  clear_screen
    xor   %ebx, %ebx
1:  shll  $1, %ebx      # time %bx by 2
    movw  %ax, %es:(%bx)# write 2 bytes to screen, 1 character displayed
    shrl  $1, %ebx
    addl  $1, %ebx
    movl  %ebx, scn_pos
    popw  %es
    popl  %ebx          # recover %ebx from stack
    ret
# end of function

system_interrupt:      #system_interrupt handler to call write_char and iret;
    push  %ds
    pushl %edx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %eax
    call write_char
    popl  %eax
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %edx
    pop   %ds
    iret
#end of system_interrupt
timer_interrupt:                #timer part 2
    pushl %eax
    movb  $0x20, %al
    outb  %al, $0x20
    cli
    movb  $1, %al
    cmpb  %al, current
    je    st0
    movb  %al, current
    call  task1
    jmp   st1
st0:movb  $0, current
    call  task0
st1:popl  %eax
    sti
    iret

#ep3 add two functions 
task0:
    pushl %eax
    pushl %ecx
    movb $0x0A, %ah     # set the colour attributes
    movb $67, %al
    int  $0x80
    movl $0xFFFF, %ecx  # pause for some time
2:  loop 2b
 #   jmp task0
    popl %ecx
    popl %eax
    ret
task1:
    pushl %eax
    pushl %ecx
    movb $0x0D, %ah     # set the colour attributes
    movb $83, %al
    int  $0x80
    movl $0xFFFF, %ecx
3:  loop 3b
    #jmp task1
    popl %ecx
    popl %eax
    ret

#ignore_int:
#    pushl %eax
#    movb  $0x0E, %ah
#    movb  $84, %al
#   # call  write_char
#    int   $0x80
#    popl  %eax
#    iret
#
#setup_ivt:
#    pushl %eax
#    pushl %edx
#    movl  $0, %edx
#    movl  $0, %eax
#    lea   ignore_int, %eax  
#loop_ivt:  
#    movl  %eax, %es:(,%edx,4)
#   # movw  $0, %es:0x2(,%edx,4)
#    addl  $1, %edx
#    cmpl  $256, %edx
#    jb    loop_ivt
#    popl  %edx
#    popl  %eax
#    ret
#
clear_screen:
    pushl %eax
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %ecx
    pushl %edx
    mov $0x0700, %ax # function 07, AL=0 means scroll whole window
    mov $0x0007, %bh # character attribute = white on black
    mov $0x0000, %cx # row = 0, col = 0
    mov $0x184f, %dx # row = 24 (0x18), col = 79 (0x4f)
    int $0x10        # call BIOS video interrupt
    popl  %edx
    popl  %ecx
    popl  %ebx
    popl  %eax
    ret

#.section .data
jump_offset : .word main
jump_segment: .word 0x0

SCN_SEL:  .word 0xb800  #! memory number where colour text starts
scn_pos:  .word 0x0     # 2 bytes to save current screen postion
current:  .byte 0x1
.org 510                # to advance the location to 510th byte
.word 0xAA55            # last 16 bits of first 512 bytes on disk

#as -o ep3.o ep3.s;ld ep3.o -o ep3 -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary;sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=ep3 -cpu max
```

Program expected to print letter C and S alternatively. As every time the timer handler runs, it check the current task if it's task0 which prints C, it switch to task 1 which prints S, vice versa. 
Actual: Only one letter printed with screen flashing.

Comment: Given that you use `movl  scn_pos, %ebx` which moves 4 bytes to _EBX_ you should be using `scn_pos:  .long 0x0` instead of `scn_pos:  .word 0x0`. In your interrupt handler you can't guarantee what the value of DS will be so you should be copying CS to DS when your interrupt handler starts (and restore it when finished) or modify you memory operands in your interrupt handler to use a segment prefix override of `%cs:`. _CS_ is the only segment register you are guaranteed to have a known value upon entry (the value 0x0000)

Comment: No need to do CLI in your interrupt handler when interrupts are already disabled when control is transferred to your interrupt vector (interrupt flag will be restored to its previous value when IRET is executed)

Comment: If only printing one character per task, then you may want to comment out or remove the delay loops.